# How do you classify packages in Enterprise Architect so that they align to TOGAF?

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect, togaf

I have a model that lists my artifacts such as catalogs of applications, servers as well as diagrams that model the environment and matrices that show relationships. I am however unclear how these can be classified so that they align to TOGAF.

For example is the classification Artifacts > Catalog > Servers correct? What if there are human elements such as Actors and documentation as well as intangible concepts and principles such as LDAP, DNS, etc.

Is there a base template that has the appropriate package structure and classification that I can use in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can look into the view and view points concept in EA, here is an [TOGAF v8 online doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf8-doc/arch/chap31.html#tag_32_04) , which shows Zachman model of various view and view points. Check the picture for Table: Mapping of Example Taxonomy of Architecture Views to Zachman Framework.

I believe for your case, the proper catalog could be **System model - Network or Technology constrained model - Network** views.

Also here is another [TOGAF v9 doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap35.html#tag_35_07), check 35.7 Recommended Architecture Views to be Developed, you could look into **35.7.3 Developing a Software Engineering View**

Comment: Thanks. I understand that there can be different views based on viewpoints but this doesn't address how artifacts are packaged. As in my example I have artifacts such as servers, documentation, applications, components, etc. I also have stakeholders.

Comment: how about follow the table here as your packaging criteria [artifacts by ADM phase](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap35.html), some of your server deployment diagram, application list and component list could be different types of catalog, matrix and diagrams in different area. E.g.detail stakeholder information and relationship of those could be in business architecture-organization and actor catalog, then actor/role matix, then business use case diagram.

Comment: Thanks. So that I understand what you mean I'll regurgitate. Do you mean to say that under each view such as business architecture, data architecture and technology architecture, the artifacts are packaged under each respective views?

Comment: business architecture, data architecture and technology architecture are all 'phases' rather than specific view or view points defined in     Architecture Development Method(ADM). Though there could be more specific viewpoints and views in each phase, e.g. follow Zachman model. You could define artifacts packaging by phases, by views, or combined. (like phase->view->artifact)

Comment: Thanks Lex Lian. I'm learning TOGAF and Zachman so am getting a little lost. Would you mind if I were to email you what I am trying to achieve? My email address is {username} at gmail dot com.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ArchiMate, also by the open group. There is an [Enterprise Architect plugin](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/tech/archimate/archimate.html) for it and it is focused on modelling the enterprise and drawing UML diagrams. They create separate packages for business, application, and technology layers.

Answer (score 0):

EA has TOGAF support, but it depends on [which edition](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html#editions) you are using. It is included in the *Ultimate* and *Business & Software Engineering* editions. For other editions, it is available for purchase as a [separate MDG Technology](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/tech/togaf/index.html).

Comment: I have the TOGAF plugin installed however it does not tell me how the models, artifacts, etc should be packaged. For example I have assets such as servers, documentation, applications, etc. I also have stakeholders, etc